# Как определить ip пользователя в Laravel + Nuxt?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, api, nuxt.js

как правильно определить ip пользователя

в NuxtJs в store index.js в методе инит делаю запрос на api и сохраняю в стор данные

```
export const state = () => ({
  geo: [],
  error: []
})

export const actions = {
  // nuxtServerInit is called by Nuxt.js before server-rendering every page
  async nuxtServerInit ({ commit, dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('storeDispatchFunc')
  },

  // axios...
  async storeDispatchFunc ({ commit }) {
    await this.$axios
      .get('api/v1/geo')
      .then((result) => {
        commit('SET_DATA', result.data.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        commit('SET_ERRORS', error)
      })
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_DATA (state, theData) {
    state.geo = theData
  },
  SET_ERRORS (state, theData) {
    state.error = theData
  }
}
```

в api на ларе вот так определяю ip

```
if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
```

уже на проекте на сайте не определяет почему-то ip

если с локалки делаю запрос на api то определяет

почему-то выдает вот такой двойной ip "37.212.42.197, 45.84.226.210"

двойной, именно когда проект уже залит на домен

Comment: Cloudflare не используете?

Comment: нет, не использую

Comment: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR насколько помню возвращает цепочку адресов, разделённых запятой, берите последний из них...

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать получить ip через объект запроса Laravel:

```
public funtion someAction (Request $request) {
    $ip = $request->ip();
}
```

Comment: выводит 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Aslero если выводит 127.0.0.1 то скорей всего вы локально определяете ip